# How to ensure a promise.then(func) has run before in another controller?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a Restangular function in controller A that needs to set up a `$rootScope` variable that is being used in controller B. How can I ensure that the Restangular function is run before controller B is initialized, or is there another way to handle this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Are controller A and B on different pages\routes?

Comment: @Chandermani yup, controllers are on the same route.

Comment: Sounds like a job for captain $rootScope.$broadcast, and his sidekick $scope.$on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to handle dependencies is to use a use a `$scope.$watch` on the variable you're waiting on and have your other code respond in the  callback.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $rootScope.resultFromControllerA
}, function(result) {
    if (result) {

        // Configure Controller B
    }
})
```

Edit, just to add since you suggested it's a promise, just set the promise on the root scope and have your other controller attach to it:

#### Controller A

```
$rootScope.controllerASetupPromise = Restangular.get()
```

#### Controller B

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $rootScope.controllerASetupPromise
}, function(thePromise) {
    if (thePromise) {

        thePromise.then(function(response) {

            // Configure Controller B
        });
    }
})
```